# How to use cache on Movieclip with createJS and Flash CC

Tags: html, caching, createjs, flash-cc

Hi all I want to ask something. I've made a game with Flash CC and createJS. it's a Drag and drop game (3 object for drag, and 3 object for drop) and a lot of vector movieclip object. But when I run it in mobile, the game looks like have a performance issues. I've read some article that talk about `caching` the object. But I'm really dont know anything about `cache` and don't know how to use it on an object like movieclip. Do you have any explanation or solution or maybe a tutorial how to use `cache` function? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Draws the display object into a new canvas, which is then used for subsequent draws. For complex content that does not change frequently (ex. a Container with many children that do not move, or a complex vector Shape), this can provide for much faster rendering because the content does not need to be re-rendered each tick. The cached display object can be moved, rotated, faded, etc freely, however if its content changes, you must manually update the cache by calling updateCache() or cache() again. You must specify the cache area via the x, y, w, and h parameters. This defines the rectangle that will be rendered and cached using this display object's coordinates.
>   http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_cache

So, you don't want to cache a playing MovieClip (you would have to update the cache every frame, which is slow). However, you could cache elements in the MC that are just being transformed.

For example, an animation of a walking character, with complex vector shapes for the arms, legs, head, and body that are being transformed (scaled, rotated, translated) to create the walk animation. You wouldn't cache the character MC, but you could cache the body parts themselves.

Comment: Thank you very much gskinner for your explanation , it really helped me to understand the `cache` thing ^_^.